# PHP Error Call to a member function format() on array

Tags: php, symfony

I have a date time field

```
    /**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $datetime;  

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $datetime
 *
 */
public function setDate($datetime)
{
    $this->datetime = $datetime;

    return $this->datetime ?? new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDate(): \DateTime
{
    return $this->datetime ?? new \DateTime();
}
```

I this error below:

Call to a member function format() on array

[image: The error on the page]

Anyone know why I get this?

Edit:

Below is the code that I use to generate a form to read in the DateTime value and then collect the data from the form and create a new entity in the table:

```
$trainingform = new Training();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($trainingform)
        ->add('Leader', TextType::class)
        ->add('Date', DateTimeType::class, ['label' => 'Date and Time'])
        ->add('topics', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Topics Being Covered'])
        ->getForm();

    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $trainingform->setLeader($request->request->get('form')['Leader']); 
        $trainingform->setDate($request->request->get('form')['Date']);
        $trainingform->setTopics($request->request->get('form')['topics']);
        $em->persist($trainingform);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: What's you $value. Your $value is an array, not an obj

Comment: The value comes from a Symfony DateTime form. `->add('Date', DateTimeType::class, ['label' => 'Date and Time']) ` in the handling, `$trainingform->setDate($request->request->get('form')['Date']);` Believe thats what your asking for

Comment: show it's value here.

Comment: Date and time value example: 2016 Sep 14 , 13 00

Comment: This is what the form looks like http://puu.sh/utRBq/abe82dc5a6.png

Comment: I mean show the value of $value in the code. use dd(), or print_r(), or var_dump() it.

Comment: Value - [ date => [ year => 2019, month => 10, day => 14 ], time => [ hour => 16, minute => 16 ] ]

Comment: so it's the reason. the $value is an array. So you cannot call format() function on an array. For an array doesn't have method format().

Comment: So what do I do to fix that?

Comment: How? I don't know where you $value come from, and where you format() come?

Comment: Edited it, now shows the code of the form and handling data

Comment: `private $datetime;` . Could you show annotations above it on your entity, please? Or how did you specify this field (yml, xml?)

Comment: I have edited it show it shows was is above @jaro1989

Comment: So, yup.. Everything is configured right, except you're trying to set array instead of DateTime object required. You can handle it manually, but surely it's better to not use request data, but form data with `$form->getData()`, where you'll see all the data submitted with correct types

Comment: Ok, I changed it to this, `$trainingform->setDate($form->getData('Date'));` however now I get this error now, http://puu.sh/uud4H/af9f876e79.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle your data correctly you should use symfony form's `getData`-method, which will transform your request to the state you've specified in your form before. In your case it should look like this:

```
    $trainingForm = new Training();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($trainingForm)
        ->add('Leader', TextType::class) // 'Leader' should be named as your property
        ->add('datetime', DateTimeType::class, ['label' => 'Date and Time']) //changed your Date to datetime as your property is
        ->add('topics', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Topics Being Covered'])  //should be named as your property as well
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Submit form']) //should be there
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request)

    if (form->isSubmitted() && form->isValid()) {
        $trainingForm= $form->getData();
        $em->persist($trainingForm);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

To avoid such inconsistency, you could specify the required type on your setter method:

```
/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $datetime
 */
public function setDate(\DateTime $datetime) //typhint added
{
    $this->datetime = $datetime;
}
```

`

Setter shouldn't return anything btw. Then you would get your error on the step you can control and you would know where you should dig after.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also I had a separate submit button on the page, just so you know.

Comment: Yeah, I know that you can render it in twig, but I like to keep it with form personally. Glad it helped. Cheers