# Symfony DateTimeField error

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I have this code which works without the date function. It updates data into MySQL.

But I keep getting an error with the DateTime field:

```
FatalThrowableError in DateTimeType.php line 53:
Call to a member function format() on array
```

It is set as a DateTime field.

```
public function EditData($id, Request $request){
  $path ='AppBundle:eqData';
  $rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($path);
  $data = $rep->getData($id);

  if ($request->isMethod('POST')){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $event = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:eqEvent')->find($id);

    $request = $request->request->all();

    $date = $request['form']['Date'];

    $edit->setDate($date);

    $em->flush();
  }

  $edit->setEventDate($data[0]->getEventDate());

  $form = $this->CreateFormBuilder($event)
  ->add('EventDate', DateTimetype::class)
  ->add('Save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'))
  ->getForm();

  return $this->render('edit.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->CreateView(),
  ));

}
```

I read already a lot, but without good result. Anyone?

Comment: You need to use DateTime object, not string. Check your object type of variable.

Comment: It is set as a DateTime object in MySQL and also in php/Symfony.

Comment: $event ¿? It's correctly initialized? Exist setEventDate(\DateTime $datetime) in the class?

Comment: The error failed in the POST ?

Comment: No, it doesn't...But when I add this:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\eqEvent::setEventDate() must be an instance of DateTime, array given, called in /DefaultController.php on line 404

Comment: Ok... check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/42600364/2209876 because i don't know as has conformed the class(attributes and methods)

Comment: Where is your **persist** without persist you can't save?

Comment: Prev to setEventDate.. print_r(get_class($data[0]->getEventDate())) and die.. check the element is DateTime..

Comment: The element shows the right information with a var_dump...

Comment: As long as you're not showing your exact code (current version of code can't work as described, since ``$event`` isn't initialized anywhere; also ``use``-statements aren't known, ...) you're not getting an answer that might solves your problem. Please post the minimum code to understand your problem, but not less.

Comment: I tried to add the necessary code. The default controller is +1000 lines of code, so that's why.
In other edit forms where no DateTime is involved, everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works is:

```
->add('Date', 'date',array('widget'=>'single_text','format'=>'d/M/y HH:mm:ss'))
```

instead of :

```
->add('Date',DateTimeType::class)
```

Comment: {{record.EventDate|date('d-m-Y H:i:s')}} in Twig was also a solution!

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
$date = $request['form']['Date'];
```

to this:

```
$dateParsed = $request['form']['Date']['year'] . '-' . $request['form']['Date']['month'] . '-' . $request['form']['Date']['day'];
$date = new \DateTime($dateParsed);
```

Comment: that's fine but I think it lacks initializing $event

Comment: Results in: Type error: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: \DateTime($format, $date) example \DateTime("Y-m-d", "2017-09-11")

Comment: try to print what contains the variable  $request['form']['Date'] please @Robbert

Comment: (array('date' => array('month' => '1', 'day' => '1', 'year' => '2019'), 'time' => array('hour' => '19', 'minute' => '0')))

Comment: try to use my new solution (I haven't tried It but the concept is clear I think) @Robbert

Comment: @ Alessandro: I get: Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: remove the [0] from the array in all its declarations so

Comment: I did, but then: Notice: Undefined index: Date

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your **class** and whats is class use:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;

********
```